# Editing environment variables from code in PyCharm?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, environment

I'm working on a subclass for ttk.frame from Tkinter that displays a pygame window. First I coded everything in IDLE and it worked. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import pygame

class pycanvas(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        #making pygame window generate inside frame
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.winfo_id())
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

        #creating pygame window
        self.canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
        self.canvas.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))
        pygame.display.init()
        pygame.display.update()
```

As you see the pycanvas can be used just like `ttk.Frame` except that it has a pygame window in it.

However this code doesn't work in PyCharm because PyCharm uses it's own environment variables. So the part where I call `os.environ` to change environment variables doesn't affect how the window is generated. In other words the pygame window, just as it would normally do, generates independently.

All I found out on google was that environment variables can be set by editing the run configs. This doesn't work for me because I need to change my environment variables inside the code.

Is there any way to change environmental variables inside my code just like I did it in IDLE instead of manually editing them?